# Background guy in tik toks

Tags: meaning, writing

Often in chinese tik tok compilations, there is a guy in the background who says something sounding like "ayodema" or something like that... I'd like to ask you what he is actual saying and what it means

Answer (score 2):

> 哎呦，我的妈
>
> āi yōu wǒ de mā

This is what you heard. It is similar to "oh my goodness" in English, which generally means that things are beyond expectation.

> 哎呦 = Oh
>
> 我的 = my
>
> 妈 literally means "mother", but it could indicate someone or something you respect